# Strange behavior drawing a path offset from a coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

Maybe someone can explain to me what's happening here. I'm trying to add a path on the very left explaining the axis. With the following code

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [x=5mm,y=5mm,
    cell/.style={draw,minimum size=5mm,inner sep=0pt},
    ]
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {0,...,4}
        \node[cell,label=center:\scriptsize $x_{\l}$] (c\i) at (0,-\i) {};

    \foreach \l in {1,2,3}
        \draw[decoration={brace},decorate] (\l*1.5-0.5,-\l+0.5) -- node[] (b\l) {} (\l*1.5-.5,-\l-2.5);

  \begin{scope}[shift={(10,-4)}]
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2}
     \foreach \j in {0,1,2} 
     \node[cell,label=center:\scriptsize $x_{\the\numexpr 4-\i-\j}$] (g\i\j) at (\j,\i) {};
  \end{scope}

  \draw[->] (b3) to [bend left=45] (g00.west);
  \draw[->] (b2) to [bend left=45] (g10.west);
  \draw[->] (b1) to [bend left=45] (g20.west);

  \draw[->] (c1.west)+(-1,0) -- node[left]{\scriptsize Time} (c5.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this output:

[image]

So far, so good. When I change the last line to

```latex
\draw[->] (c1.west)+(-1,0) -- node[left]{\scriptsize Time} (c5.west)+(-1,0);
```

then this happens:

[image]

This has me scratching my head. Am I not using the syntax correctly? What is going on with that path?

Comment: you may like to accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left of the answer and upvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line -- and use the `calc` tikzlibrary

```
\draw[->] ($(c1.west)+(-1,0)$) -- node[left]{\scriptsize Time} ($(c5.west)+(-1,0)$);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea why my code doesn't work?

Comment: the calculation part needs to be enclosed inthe syntax as above

Comment: But why does it work for the first coordinate? :->

Comment: which coord are you referring

Comment: `(c1.west)+(-1,0)`

Comment: no idea -- probably aseparate question for the veterans